# Deserialize Existing XML file in VB.NET

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

I am changing a VB.NET application to use XmlSerializer instead of XMLDocument to read/write to an XML settings file and want to preserve backwards compatibility.

Here is a sample of the XML file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <postHistory>
      <postFile>a.txt</postFile>
      <postFile>b.txt</postFile>
      <postFile>c.txt</postFile>
    </postHistory>
  </appSettings>
  <SettingsPath>d.txt</SettingsPath>
</configuration>
```

Here are the classes I came up with that correctly de-serialize the original file.

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.Collections.Generic

<XmlRoot("configuration")>
Public Class LocalSettings
  <XmlElement("appSettings")>
  Public appSettings As New postHistory()
  Public SettingsPath As String = ""
End Class

Public Class postHistory
  Public postHistory As New SubSettings()
End Class

Public Class SubSettings
  <XmlElement("postFile")>
  Public postHistory As New List(Of String)
End Class
```

This is the code used to de-serialize the file:

```
  Public Shared Function GetLocalSettings(ByVal filePath As String) As LocalSettings
    Dim lSettings As New LocalSettings()

    Try
      Dim xs As New XmlSerializer(GetType(LocalSettings))
      Using fs As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)
        lSettings = xs.Deserialize(fs)
      End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
      ' Handle exception
    End Try

    Return lSettings
  End Function
```

This solution works but feels awkward. Is there a more optimal way to de-serialize that doesn't require nesting the 'postHistory' list within two sub-classes?

Comment: What's generating that XML? It seems to have the layout of a standard app.config file right up until you get to the contents of `appSettings`.

It could be that there's a better way to do this, but what comes to mind at the moment is two things: 1) this is happening because that's what the layout of your XML is, and the XMLDeserializer is naive, expecting to create objects based on the XML structure; and 2) It works, I'd go with that.

Comment: Only if you modify the xml and remove the posthistory tag.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback suggestions. I want to keep the solution as simple as possible and was just looking for any alternatives within the .NET serialization framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`XmlArrayAttribute(string name)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify that a list should be serialized in two levels, with the outer container element having the specified name.  Then you can use [`XmlArrayItemAttribute(string name)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify the inner element name.

Thus:

```
<XmlRoot("configuration")>
Public Class LocalSettings
  <XmlElement("appSettings")>
  Public appSettings As New postHistory()
  Public SettingsPath As String = ""
End Class

Public Class postHistory
  <XmlArray("postHistory")>
  <XmlArrayItem("postFile")>
  Public postHistory As New List(Of String)
End Class
```

This allows the `SubSettings` class to be eliminated.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PDFdTx).

For more information see [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: That is the syntax I was looking for, thanks! Works great!